# Re-use threads in CUDA

Tags: arrays, cuda, nvidia

I have a large series of numbers, in an array, about 150MB of numbers, and I need to find consecutive sequences of numbers, the sequences might be from 3 to 160 numbers. so to make it simple, I decided the each thread should start such as ThreadID = CellID

So thread0 looks at cell0, and if the number in cell0 matches my sequence, then, thread0 = cell1 and so on, and if the numbed does not match, the thread is stopped and I do that for my 20000 threads.

So that works out, fine but I wanted to know how to reuse threads, because the array in which i'm looking for the series of number is much bigger.

So should I divide my array in smaller arrays, and load them into shared memory, and loop over the number of smaller arrays and (eventually pad the last one). Or should I keep the big array in global memory, and have my thread to be to ThreadID = cellID and then ThreadID = cellID+20000 etc. or is there a better way to go through.

*To clarify* : At the moment i use 20 000 threads, 1 Array of numbers in Global Memory (150MB), and a sequence of numbers in shared memory (eg: 1,2,3,4,5), represented as an array. Thread0 start at Cell0, and look if the cell0 in global memory, is equal to cell0 in shared memory, if yes, thread0 compare cell1 in global memory, to cell1 in shared memory, and so on until there is a full match.

If the numbers in both (global and shared memory) cells are not equal, that thread is simply discarded. Since, most of the numbers in the Global memory Array will not match the first number of my sequence. I thought it was a good idea to use one thread to match Cell_N in GM to Cell_N in ShM and overlap the threads.  and this technique allows coalesced memory access the first time, since every thread from 0 to 19 999 will access contiguous memory.

But what I would like to know, is "what would be the best way to re-use the threads" that have been discarded, or the threads that finished to match. To be able to match the entire array of 150MB instead of simply match (20000 numbers + (length of sequence -1)).

Comment: Why can't you use common `ID = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;` approach instead of putting threads into loop?

Comment: Your question is not much clear to me. At the beginning you say: _I need to find consecutive sequences of numbers_. This means that you can have multiple possible consecutive sequences, for example, `1,4,7,14` and `5,8,11,64` and so on and so forth. Later on you say: _the numbers in `cell0` match my sequence_. This means that you are searching for a specific sequence. Could you clarify this point? In the latter case, it seems that you are looking for a template matching like algorithm and, in this case, I would direct you towards a Smith-Waterman like algorithm.

Comment: Correctly formulating your problem is a big step towards its solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I clarified the problem, although I doubt smith-waterman is a solution to this problem, the matching of the numbers is pretty forward, I just would like to know how to re-use thread properly in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "what would be the best way to re-use the threads" that have been discarded, or the threads that finished to match. To be able to match the entire array of 150MB instead of simply match (20000 numbers + (length of sequence -1)).

You can re-use threads in a fashion similar to the canonical [CUDA reduction sample](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction) (using the final implementation as a reference).

```
int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
while (idx < DSIZE){
  perform_sequence_matching(idx);
  idx += gridDim.x*blockDim.x;
  }
```

In this way, with an arbitrary number of threads in your grid, you can cover an arbitrary problem size (`DSIZE`);